# Why is the discord bot not talking?

Tags: python, discord.py

The discord bot is not answering back when I said `!hello`. It does not respond. What is the issue?

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have loggin in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
   return

   if message.conetnt.startswith('!hello'):
     await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Content is spelled wrong. It should be `content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled `content`. This should work:

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have loggin in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
   return

   if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
     await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Could you tell us, what error message you are getting?

Comment: i stoped using stackoverflow so i just opened it i am confused so i mark your as correct